# installing polar_scan_matcher wrapper

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to get this package in order to use it or port it to the newest ROS version:

http://wiki.ros.org/polar_scan_matcher

However, I could only find this, which seems to be basically only the scan matching function without the wrapper, which could save me a lot of time:

http://www.irrc.monash.edu.au/adiosi/downloads.html

Do you know where I can find the wrapper?
The github archive points to a library that only seems to be using CSM by Andrea Censi to do the scan matching and not polar scan matching.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190042/installing-polar_scan_matcher-wrapper/) by [lucaluca](https://answers.ros.org/users/19657/lucaluca/) on ROS Answers with karma: 74 on 2014-08-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you install [Scan_tools](http://wiki.ros.org/scan_tools?distro=fuerte) you could use the Polar Scan Matching directly. Check the wiki and enter to the git files for clearer install instructions. You'll find everything from the previous link.

Best!

---

Originally posted by [Victor Gomez](https://answers.ros.org/users/12286/victor-gomez/) with karma: 50 on 2015-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-10-17**:
Note that `scan_tools` is recently released into Indigo and Jade so that you don't need to source build it.